# Menu navigation to multiple "windows" in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, menu

I'm coming from VB6. There I had a main form with a menu. The documents(user interfaces) were usercontrols. The user selected his required document from the menu and then the required usercontrol appeared on the main form.
Is this a best practice in WPF or are there better solutions? (obviously the "main form from VB6" in WPF would be a *System.Windows.Window*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I get what you want to do: But usually you have a [ContentControl](http://www.wpftutorials.com/2011/03/content-controls.html). You load the UserControl you want into it (using the myContentControl.Content property).

If you are new to WPF, make sure you check out the [MVVM pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/126249/MVVM-Pattern-in-WPF-A-Simple-Tutorial-for-Absolute). It greatly increases the quality of your code, even though it makes some things a little tricky :).